# unable to capture wget response when called from perl script

Tags: external, wget

I am a newbee to perl and have been trying to capture the message displayed on the command screen after executing a wget request. the wget is called from inside perl script, but my all efforts to capture it has failed. 
I have tried: exec, system, open file, backticks, qx but didn't get the required result. I can't install additional packages with CPAN so other modules can't be used.

it looks something like:

`#wget http://xxx.broker:8087/brocker-v2/wallet/customerbalance/addon_id/xxxxx/country_id/oml/msisdn/xxxxx/pin/xxxx/`

the response on the screen is like:

> connecting to server....
>   some response and details here
>   response ok 200

and the above lines are what i want to capture in a variable or file.

some of the things i have tried:

```
@wget_response = qx($wget_command);

($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture {
 system( $wget_command, @wget_resp );
};

open (my $my_file, '>', 'wget_response') or die "Could not open file: $!";
my $output = `$wget_command`;
die "$!" if $?;
print $my_file $output;
```

Comment: Try redirecting stderr, so wget (args) 2>&1

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, try redirecting stderr with your wget command, so your line starting with my $output would become:
    my $output = `$wget_command 2>&1`;

That should get all the output in your variable.

Comment: thanks for the reply, still no success, i get:

wget response file contains: **GLOB(0x1ceae440)**